# Translating between different database schema with similar attributes

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

Is it possible to translate between two different database schema, possibly using different DBMS so that the user can query an intermediary schema representation and the query is translated to the underlying sql query to return results.

An example

```
Underlying database      Intermediate Representation
--------------------    --------------
| _____   _____   |     |  _______  |
|| Men | |Women|  |     | |People | |
||-----| |-----|  |     | |-------| |
||Name:| |Name:|  |---->| |Name:  | |
||Age: | |Age: |  |     | |Age:   | |
||_____| |_____|  |     | |Gender:| |
|                 |     | |_______| | 
|_________________|     |___________|
```

I would like a query on the intermediate representation such as

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Gender == "Male";
```

To translate on the underlying database to

```
SELECT * FROM Men;
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database))?

Comment: I've heard of them but I would not say I'm familiar. I will look into it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
create table men (
  name varchar(255) primary key,
  age smallint not null
);

create table women (
  name varchar(255) primary key,
  age smallint not null
);

create view people as 
  select
    name,
    age,
    'Male' as gender
  from men
  union
  select
    name,
    age,
    'Female' as gender
  from women;
```

Querying:

```
insert into men values ('John', 25);
insert into women values ('Jane', 25);

select * from people where gender = 'Male';
```

Result:

```
Name  Age  Gender
John  25   Male
```

Fiddle with it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/85939/2